# increase form height

Tags: c#, .net

How can I increase over 1062px form height in c# forms application ?

I can also use scrollable component for this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form cannot be taller than the working area of your screen.

**EDIT**: You can make a `Panel` control and set its `AutoScroll` property to true.
However, this will result in a very poor user experience.

You should rethink your UI.

Comment: As far as I know you can set it as much as you like and at run-time it will be scaled down.

Comment: yes you are right. But how can I use scrollable component on the form?

Answer (score 0):

While the form cannot be taller than the working area of your screen you can set `AutoScroll` property on the form instead:

```
form1.AutoScroll = true;
```

This will have the scrollbars to automatically appear when the form contests are larger than its visible area.